# Viewpager with fragments: onAttached not called for all fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, robospice, fragment-lifecycle

I have been using Robospice to complete my network operations. In Robospice, they recommend that the `SpiceService` (an extension of the android service class) be started in a fragment's `onAttach()` method:

> Other solution is to use second approach which is getting own
>   `SpiceManager` in `Fragment.onAttach(...)` and releasing the `SpiceManager`
>   in `Fragment.onDetach()`

https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Advanced-RoboSpice-Usages-and-FAQ

So I have been trying to do so but I see that sometimes the fragment's `onAttach()` method is not called at all when you use fragments with a `Viewpager`. I have created a github repo showing this problem:

https://github.com/Winghin2517/ViewPagerFragmentSample

In my github repo, I have 3 fragments and one viewpager. I'm logging when each fragment's `onAttach` method is called and the results are erratic. Closing the app and restarting it produces this sometimes:

```
12-27 12:55:17.085 8831-8831/? E/Fragment2: onAttachedActivity
12-27 12:55:17.085 8831-8831/? E/Fragment2: onAttachedContext
12-27 12:55:17.097 8831-8831/? E/Fragment1: onAttachedActivity
12-27 12:55:17.097 8831-8831/? E/Fragment1: onAttachedContext
```

or just this:

```
12-27 12:56:30.018 8864-8864/? E/Fragment2: onAttachedActivity
12-27 12:56:30.022 8864-8864/? E/Fragment2: onAttachedContext
```

I'm logging both when `public void onAttach(Context context)` is called for api 23 (this shows in the log as "onAttachedContext") and when `public void onAttach(Activity activity)` is called for api below 23 (this shows in the log as "onAttachedActivity") even though I'm using the support Library 23.

It is seldom that all 3 fragment's `onAttach` methods are called each time the app starts which means that my robospice service for network operations are also not started occasionally leaving the app hanging.

How do I get the app to call all the onAttach methods for all fragments on start?